# How to improve CNN model reaching loss plateau?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am using TensorFlow in Python 3 to create a CNN that creates a multi class (i.e. expected output is 3 probabilities out of 92) based on a vector of photon energies shape(20, 1).
My model below is a result of multiple iterations and gradually increasing complexity.

However, the model seems to consistently reach a certain loss value no matter what additions (or reductions) I do.

The code below is the model along with some hyper parameters that I am optimising using Keras-Tuner.

```
hp_learning_rate = hp.Choice('learning_rate', values = [1e-2, 1e-5, 3e-4, 5e-5, 5e-6])

hp_activation_C_1 = hp.Choice('activation_c1', values=["relu", "swish"])
hp_activation_C_2 = hp.Choice('activation_c2', values=["relu", "swish"])
hp_activation_D_1 = hp.Choice('activation_d1', values=["softsign", "relu", "swish"])
hp_activation_D_2 = hp.Choice('activation_d2', values=["softsign", "relu", "swish"])

hp_drop = hp.Choice('dropout_%', values=[0.05, 0.04, 0.03, 0.02])

hp_filters_1 = hp.Choice('num_filters_1', values=[32, 64, 96])
hp_filters_2 = hp.Choice('num_filters_2', values=[64, 96, 128, 256])
hp_filters_3 = hp.Choice('num_filters_3', values=[96, 128, 256, 384])

hp_kernel_size_1 = hp.Choice('kernel_size_1', values=[3, 5])

hp_units_1 = hp.Int('units_1', min_value = 64, max_value = 2624, step = 128)
hp_units_2 = hp.Int('units_2', min_value = 64, max_value = 2624, step = 128)
# hp_pool_size_1 = hp.Choice('pool_size_1', values=[2, 3, 4])



model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(filters=hp_filters_1, kernel_size=hp_kernel_size_1,
                 activation=hp_activation_C_1, input_shape=(20, 1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(hp_drop))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=hp_filters_2, kernel_size=3, activation=hp_activation_C_2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(hp_drop))
model.add(AveragePooling1D(pool_size=3, strides=2))
# model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=hp_pool_size_1,strides=3))


model.add(Conv1D(filters=hp_filters_3, kernel_size=3, activation=hp_activation_C_2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(hp_drop))
model.add(AveragePooling1D(pool_size=3,strides=2))
# model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2,strides=2))


model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(hp_drop))


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(hp_units_1, activation=hp_activation_D_1))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(hp_drop))
model.add(Dense(hp_units_2, activation=hp_activation_D_2))
model.add(Dense(92, activation='softmax'))

    
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_mse',
                           patience=5,
                           restore_best_weights=True,
                           min_delta=0.00005)


reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor="val_mse",
                              factor=0.5,
                              patience=3,
                              min_lr=1e-6,
                              min_delta=0.00008)
```

---

So my question is, am I overcomplicating the model for the required objective? And how can I improve that performance to further reduce the loss?

Comment: Here good basics are explained by Andrew Ng https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1ka6a13S9I

Comment: @user3184950, I'm afraid this lecture did not quite answer my question. However, Andrew was talking about one of the solution may be that the model needs to be bigger. **Do you know what he would mean by that (more number of filters/neurons, more number of conv/dense layers, or something else)?**

Comment: I was hinting on the careful examination of loss graphs. I hope you learned something anyway. In CNN, bigger can be 2 things: (1) More filters in CNN, (2) More Layers/Blocks of typical CNN layers. You could add 2 CNN layers of kernel size 3, or repeat a typical Block you have (CNN, batch, drop, downsample)

Comment: Yeah I definitely learned something, and thanks a lot for that!! Okay, that makes sense. And for anyone who might read this later, I did add another block and so far it's showing better performance, but still yet to finish.

Answer (score 2):

You might try using an adjustable learning rate. The Keras callback `ReduceLROnPlateau` makes this easy to do. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/reduce_lr_on_plateau/) Set the callback to monitor validation loss. My recommended code is shown below:

```
red_lr=tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau( monitor="val_loss",factor=0.5,
    patience=2,verbose=1,mode="auto", min_delta=0.0001, cooldown=0, min_lr=0)
```

in `model.fit` add `callbacks=[red_lr]`

Comment: I already had that in my code, I just forgot to show it. Any other suggestions?